Windows 11 - Can't access certain websites on all browsers (Temporary solution found, only works for a very brief time)
When I try to access a few specific websites in Chrome, I get the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error. The websites cannot be accessed from Firefox or Edge either. Using the route /f command in cmd and then restarting my computer fixes the issue for a few minutes, but the problem returns very quickly.

Have you tried netsh int ip reset and netsh winsock reset?

Yes, I have tried those.

Is DNS lookup failing? Try a different DNS provider. Check the IP address at https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3agoogle.com&run=toolpage, for example, and ping the site by name, e.g., google.com, and by IP address (e.g., 172.253.63.100, for one of their many servers). If IP ping works, and by name, not, then it's almost certainly DNS lookup issue.

It's not a DNS lookup issue. Both pings work.
